# How and where should I create this transactional method?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, model, transactional

I'm using Python 3.7.  In a service class, I have these statements ...

```
article.first_appeared_date = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
article.save()

ArticleStat.objects.save_main_article(article)
```

The first pair of statements updates an attribute for a single object and the second statement creates a bunch of separate objects, using the first object.  What i would like is for the whole thing to be executed as a transaction, whereby everything succeeds or no changes to the database occur if something fails.  I'm unclear as to best practices in Python.  Where would a method like this go?  Does putting it in a manager class make it transactional?

Comment: Checkout the [`transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) decorator/context-manager. It is well documented.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import transaction

 with transaction.atomic():
    article.first_appeared_date = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    article.save()

    ArticleStat.objects.save_main_article(article)
```

You could implement a method for this in some of your models or even in a view which you call from your service. Most of the time, you want to put code like this in some view (or function that is called in a view).

However, if what you want is execute `ArticleStat.objects.save_main_article(article)` every time you `save` an article you should look at [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/), specifically [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal.

Take a look to the docs for transactions here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: Thanks.  The code I listed appears in a service class.  In other frameworks I've worked with it seems like transaction code should go in a DAO class or a model.  What's the best place in Django for transactional logic?

Comment: @Dave I've edited my answer to address you about your question about the best place for transactional logic, be aware transactional logic is not a must for achieving what you want.

Comment: In your edit you mention "post_save," but does taht achieve teh same thing?  Couldn't something fail in a post_save while the regular save succeeds?

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. If you need to rollbak the changes if ArticleStat.objects.save_main_article fails just stick to the first part of the answer and use the transaction context manager